# How can I union multiple tables from a database that end with same characters in their name?

Tags: sql, union, union-all

I am trying to union over 30 tables in my database without listing them all. They all end with the same last four characters in their name.

I've tried listing them all but would need a more efficient way to identify all tables that end with the four characters. I've tried searching for a way to search the name of the tables.

```
select * from [dbo].[AL2019CLFC]
  union
  select * from [dbo].[AR2019CLFC]
  union 
  select * from [dbo].[AZ2019CLFC]
```

.....

I expect a way to identify the last four characters 'CLFC' from all the tables and union them.

Comment: Specify your DB engine. This is not possible in SQL Server. I doubt is possible on any other RDBMS.

Comment: This is in SQL server 2014

Comment: Do these tables have the same structure? If so, you might want to consider having them all in the same table (which would certainly make your query easier). If these are actually different entities, you could possibly generate dynamic SQL. However, as @RicardoC notes, you're almost certainly going to need to list each table in your query.

Comment: @Zack Judging by the table names, they are the consequence of crappy software design and created automatically every year. It is safe to assume the same structure, otherwise a union would not work ;) but you are completely right, yes sir.

Comment: Yes they are the same structure

Comment: Tag with your DBMS. [ask] [mcve] Clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest querying from the system list of tables and building out your sql statement.  Then copying the results back into your querying window.  Technically you could make a stored procedure that would build up a string and then run executesql to get the results.

Note: the examples below will give a trailing UNION keyword which should be removed.  Again, if you wanted to get fancier, you could sql around it, but hopefully this will be enough to get you going.

MS SQL Server:

```
select 
'SELECT * FROM ' + name + ' UNION ' query
from sys.tables
where name like '%CLFC'
```

Oracle:

```
select 
'SELECT * FROM ' || table_name || ' UNION ' query
from user_tables
where table_name like '%CLFC'
```

Comment: You may wan to add the actual answer of "no, is not possibe" then I would state your answer as an alternative, not just a suggestion. He has no choice.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment (and your overly negative comments in the original post).  To me it seemed the main gist of the question was how to get the names of all the tables that ended with a set of characters (not everyone knows about sys.tables).  So my answer probably will help him solve his goal.  And about the "not possible" comment, I could definitely whip out a stored procedure that generates the sql statement and sends it to the database, but it seemed like overkill at this point, when the need was just to easily get the tables.